# SQL Server running total with dbmail when total met or exceeded

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cumulative-sum, dbmail

I am able to get a running total via script--but what I can't seem to do is isolate the line where I have met or exceeded a certain value...

```
SELECT 
    column1, 
    (SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table WHERE column2 <= t1.column2)
FROM 
    table  t1
```

Ultimately what I would want to do is create a trigger to send dbmail when the Sum of column1 meets or exceeds (n)...help me obi-wan

Comment: Are you using sql-server? If yes, what edition?

Comment: yes, sql - server 2008 r2 -- I thought about creating this as a view and then sending the dbmail...but will this be possible in automated manner or would it be necessary to create a SP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL-Server 2008 you can use next solution:

> ```
> DECLARE @TBL TABLE(id int, amount int);
> INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES
> (1, 100), (2, 100), (3, 60), (4, 200), (5, 100);
>
> SELECT     t1.ID, t1.amount, SUM(t2.amount) as CumTotal
> FROM       @TBL t1
> CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
>        FROM @TBL
>        WHERE ID <= t1.id) t2
> GROUP BY   t1.ID, t1.amount
> HAVING     SUM(t1.amount) < 300
> ORDER BY   t1.ID
> ;
> ```

This is the result:

> ```
> ID | amount | CumTotal
> -: | -----: | -------:
>  1 |    100 |      100
>  2 |    100 |      200
>  3 |     60 |      260
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=69ab8fba94251037480afa767f780174)*

Although this solution works well, it is not recommendable on terms of performance.

In this case the best option is to use a CURSOR.

> ```
> DECLARE @CS table (id int, amount int, total int);
> DECLARE @id int, @amount int;
> DECLARE @CumSum int = 0;
> DECLARE c CURSOR
>     LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
>     FOR SELECT ID, amount
>         FROM @TBL
>         ORDER BY [id];
>  
> OPEN c;
> FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @id, @amount
>  
> WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @CumSum + @amount < 300 
> BEGIN
>     SET @CumSum = @CumSum + @amount;
>     INSERT @CS (id, amount,  total)
>     SELECT @id, @amount, @CumSum;
>     FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @id, @amount
> END
>
> CLOSE c;
> DEALLOCATE c;
>  
> SELECT   id, amount, total
> FROM     @CS
> ORDER BY id;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> id | amount | total
> -: | -----: | ----:
>  1 |    100 |   100
>  2 |    100 |   200
>  3 |     60 |   260
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d0c53307d66336b8ce4fda3d524eb06f)*

**Next answer can be used on SQL-SERVER 2012 and above**

You can use a cumulative sum using a WINDOW function and SUM() ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING.

Have a look at [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

> ```
> DECLARE @TBL TABLE(id int, amount int);
> INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES
> (1, 100), (2, 100), (3, 60), (4, 200), (5, 100);
> ```

Next query returns a cumulative sum:

> ```
> SELECT ID, 
>        SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumTotal
> FROM   @TBL
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | CumTotal
> -: | -------:
>  1 |      100
>  2 |      200
>  3 |      260
>  4 |      460
>  5 |      560
> ```

The problem is that you cannot stop it, you need to calculate all records, and then you can apply a where clause just to filter the records.

> ```
> WITH CSum As
> (
>     SELECT ID, 
>            SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumTotal
>     FROM   @TBL
> )
> SELECT   ID, CumTotal
> FROM     CSum
> WHERE    CumTotal < 300
> ORDER BY ID
> ;
> ```

This is the final result:

> ```
>  
> ID | CumTotal
> -: | -------:
>  1 |      100
>  2 |      200
>  3 |      260
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=892038e5460d9a26c9e2b5e59b3e5659)*

Comment: Its been a while but is sum() over in 2008 ?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I know that MS docs are not always correct, hoewever according to MS it is. But I'll confirm it.

Comment: If not, perhaps a CROSS APPLY

Comment: @JohnCappelletti it is not accepted on 2008. I'll try with CROSS APPLY, thanks.

Comment: @McNets...thanks for the queries....What if I want to identify which ID from the cumTotal met or crossed the 300 threshhold and would it be possible to create a trigger on this and fire off a dbmail?   Like 300 is the goal and a notification or alert is sent notifying that it happened.

Comment: @Nick that should be on a different question (add a link to this one, if you post it)